# reg: what is the library dependency for sqlContext?

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark, jdbc

More detail as below:---

We have spark environment 1.6.1,Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_77).

I made a runnable jar with the "library handling" option as "Extract required libraries into generated jar". 
I executed the jar in the spark env, with below spark-submit options

spark-submit --class  spark_sqlserver_Conn.jar --master yarn

I did some research in and out of Stackoverflow, and I did find solutions, but they are not working for me.

So, what would be the right maven dependencies that I am suppose to configure?

I am also getting error as below:-
in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

```
    package spark_sqlserver.tblcreation

            import java.util.Properties
            import java.sql.DriverManager
            import java.sql.Connection
            import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
            import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

            object SQLServerTbleCreate {  
                def main (args: Array[String]){              
                  val conf = new SparkConf()
                                 .setAppName("test SQL")
                                 .setMaster("path to Spark Master Server")
                                 .set("spark.executor.memory","1g");
                  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
                  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.SQLContext(sc)  

                  var props= new java.util.Properties()
                  props.setProperty("driver",                                                                                                                                                                          "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

         val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map( "url" ->      "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx:xxxx/xxx?user=xxxxx&password=xxxxx", 
"dbtable"-> "xxxx")).load()

         val test = sqlContext.sql("SELECT xxxx ,xxxx FROM xxxxx")
         test.show(10)

          }
        }
```

My eclipse is configured with "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\server\jvm.dll"

eclipse MARS2

I have sqljdbc4-2.0.jar bundled through "build path"

Regards,
Amitesh Sahay

Comment: Could you post your pom file ?

Comment: <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
   </dependency>   
   <dependency>   
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>   
   </dependency>   
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>  
  </dependencies>   
</project>

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be class-path issue than version conflict. Make sure, your driver is in your class path.You can also ensure it from eclipse by right clicking the project.

*In Eclipse by right-clicking on the Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar.*

Comment: Hello Balaji, Yes, I can say that its more of a classpath for jdbc driver. But I really don't know how to fix it. I tried looking for the class path as per your instruction, but there are many options, please guide me to exact path for that

Comment: Hello Balaji, I ot what what you wanted to convey. I moved the sqljdbc4.jar up, and tried, but its not working either

Comment: Hello Balaji, I have already done that, and I can see my sqljdbc4.jar within my project as infomed by me initially.

Answer (score 0):

First change your code like

```
package spark_sqlserver.tblcreation

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SQLServerTbleCreate {  
    def main (args: Array[String]){              
         val conf = new SparkConf()
                    .setAppName("test SQL")                    
                    .set("spark.executor.memory","1g");
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.SQLContext(sc)  

        val jdbcSqlConnStr = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx;databaseName=xxx;user=xxx;password=xxx;"

        val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> jdbcSqlConnStr, "dbtable" -> jdbcDbTable)).load()


         val test = sqlContext.sql("SELECT xxxx ,xxxx FROM xxxxx")
         test.show(10)

        }
}
```

Then you need provide correct syntax for launching your app and also provide required dependencies with `--jars` parameter:

```
spark-submit --class "your main class full reference" --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --jars "full path to your jars with comma delimiter" "your jar package" "args"
```

e.g.

```
spark-submit --class com.run.Main --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --jars /home/user/test.jar,/home/user/log.jar application.jar "Hello!"
```

Comment: Hi, My spark-submit syntax is right, I have cross verified at many level, while posting here, I might had made a mistake. My main intention is to make a jar , which include each and every dependencies, so that we need not give any command line argument.Anyway, I will still try your suggestion

Comment: I just executed with your instructions,
spark-submit --class com.xxx.SQLConn spark_sqlserver_Conn.jar --jars /usr/iop/123/spark/lib/sqljdbc4.jar --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn.
I still get same error

Comment: please explain "application.jar", what would I mention there?

Comment: Application jar is your uber jar or fat jar which includes your main/runner class

Comment: I tried to execute the jar file exactly th eway you had saked me to, but now, I get new error

 spark-submit --class com.sqlSpark.SQLConn --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --jars  /usr/iop/4/spark/lib/sqljdbc4.jar application-jar spark_sqlserver_Conn.jar.

below is the errror

FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/METNET/at732615/poc/application-jar does not exist

Comment: going forward, I built two jars, one that contain sqljdbc4.jar, and the other that doesn't. There is a difference in the run time error. Once with the sqljdbc4.jar gives ".ClassNotFoundException: com.Spark.SparkSql" error, and one without the jar gives "no suitable driver"...